extending trace to measurable operators
For a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A}$, with semifinite, normal, faithful trace, $\tau$, the space $L^0(\mathcal{A},\tau)$ of all $\tau$-measurable operators, is defined to be the all closed, densely-defined operators $x$ on the underlying Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ such that commute with every isometry in $\mathcal{A}'$, and for which $\tau(\chi_{[\lambda,\infty)}(|x|))<\infty$ for some $\lambda>0$. The trace $\tau$ on $\mathcal{A}_+$ can be extended to $L_+^0$ by $\tau(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\mu_t(x)dt$, where $\mu_t(x)=\text{inf}\{\lambda\geq 0: \tau(\chi_{[\lambda,\infty)}(|x|))\leq t\}$.
I believe I see that $\mathcal{A}\subset L^0(A,\tau)$, but I'm a little unsure why $\int_0^{\infty}\mu_t(x)dt$ agrees with $\tau(x)$ on $\mathcal{A}_+$. It looks to be analogous to the statement that $||f||_1=||f^*||_1$, where $f$ is an $L^1$ function and $f^*$ its decreasing rearrangement. Can anyone give a sketch of how this works?

$\tau$ induces a measure on the spectrum of $|x|$, so this is just $|f|_1 = |f^\ast|_1$, not just similar to it.
